# sending and receiving files socket programming

Tags: c#, sockets

i am developing two application one is server application and other is for handheld device 
application both communicate using wireless connection.here client is handheld and server is 
my computer where server application running. when i send files from client to server it send
perfectly without any error but when client request for files the server produce error
something like
 "No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 192.168.1.5:9050"

server side code:

```
    private bool SendData(string StrIP)
    {

        try
        {
            string strmyFile = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\" + "XML" + @"\Login.xml";
            char[] delimiter = splitter.ToCharArray();
            split = strmyFile.Split(delimiter);
            int limit = split.Length;
            fName = split[limit - 1].ToString();

            byte[] fileName = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(fName); //file name
            byte[] fileData = File.ReadAllBytes(strmyFile); //file
            using (FileStream stream = File.OpenRead(strmyFile))
            {
                fileData = new byte[stream.Length];
                stream.Read(fileData, 0, fileData.Length);
            }

            byte[] fileNameLen = BitConverter.GetBytes(fileName.Length); //lenght of file name
            clientData = new byte[4 + fileName.Length + fileData.Length];

            fileNameLen.CopyTo(clientData, 0);
            fileName.CopyTo(clientData, 4);
            fileData.CopyTo(clientData, 4 + fileName.Length);

            System.Net.IPAddress ipAdd = System.Net.IPAddress.Parse(StrIP);

            try
            {
                Socket clientSock = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
                IPEndPoint ipEnd = new IPEndPoint(ipAdd, 9050);
                clientSock.Connect(ipEnd); //target machine's ip address and the port number
                clientSock.Send(clientData);
                clientSock.Close();
                ind = 1;

                //Socket Sock = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
                //IPEndPoint ipEnd = new IPEndPoint(ipAdd, 9050);
                //Sock.Bind(ipEnd);//target machine's ip address and the port number
                //Sock.Listen(100);

                //Socket clientSock = Sock.Accept();

                //clientSock.Send(clientData);
                //clientSock.Close();
                //ind = 1;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                req = false;
                return false;

            }
            req = true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
        return true;
    }


    public class StateObject
    {
        // Client socket.
        public Socket workSocket = null;

        public const int BufferSize = 1024 * 5000;
        // Receive buffer.
        public byte[] buffer = new byte[BufferSize];
    }

    public static ManualResetEvent allDone = new ManualResetEvent(false);

    public void StartListening()
    {


        byte[] bytes = new Byte[1024 * 5000];
        IPEndPoint ipEnd = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 9050);
        Socket listener = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        try
        {
            listener.Bind(ipEnd);
            listener.Listen(100);

            while (true)
            {
                allDone.Reset();
               // string ip = listener.RemoteEndPoint.ToString();
                listener.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(AcceptCallback), listener);
                allDone.WaitOne();

            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }

    }


    public void AcceptCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {

        allDone.Set();


        Socket listener = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;
        Socket handler = listener.EndAccept(ar);

        StateObject state = new StateObject();
        state.workSocket = handler;
        handler.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0,
        new AsyncCallback(ReadCallback), state);

        flag = 0;

    }

    private bool req = false;
    public void ReadCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        try
        {

            int fileNameLen = 1;
            String content = String.Empty;
            StateObject state = (StateObject)ar.AsyncState;
            Socket handler = state.workSocket;
            string[] str = new string[2];
            str = handler.RemoteEndPoint.ToString().Split(':');
            string path = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\TEST\\" + str[0].ToString();
            if (!Directory.Exists(path))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
            }
            if (req == false)
            {
                Sender snddata = new Sender();
                snddata.sendme(str[0].ToString());
                SendData(str[0].ToString());
            }

            int bytesRead = handler.EndReceive(ar);

            if (bytesRead > 0)
            {
                    if (flag == 0)
                    {
                        fileNameLen = BitConverter.ToInt32(state.buffer, 0);
                        string fileName = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(state.buffer, 4, fileNameLen);
                        receivedPath = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\TEST\\" + str[0].ToString() + @"\" + fileName;
                        flag++;
                    }
                    if (flag >= 1)
                    {
                        BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(File.Open(receivedPath, FileMode.Append));
                        if (flag == 1)
                        {
                            writer.Write(state.buffer, 4 + fileNameLen, bytesRead - (4 + fileNameLen));
                            flag++;
                        }
                        else
                            writer.Write(state.buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                        writer.Close();
                        handler.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0,
                        new AsyncCallback(ReadCallback), state);
                    }
            }
            else
            {

                Invoke(new MyDelegate(LabelWriter));
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);

        }
    }
public class Sender
{
    public void sendme(string strIP)
    {
        try
        {
           // MessageBox.Show("That program can transfer small file. I've test up to 850kb file");
            IPEndPoint ipEnd = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 9050);
            Socket sock = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.IP);
            sock.Bind(ipEnd);
            sock.Listen(100);

            while (true)
            {
                //clientSock is the socket object of client, so we can use it now to transfer data to client
                Socket clientSock = sock.Accept();


                string fileName =  "Login.xml";// "Your File Name";
                string filePath = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\" + "XML" + @"\" ;//Your File Path;
                byte[] fileNameByte = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(fileName);

                byte[] fileData = File.ReadAllBytes(filePath + fileName);
                byte[] clientData = new byte[4 + fileNameByte.Length + fileData.Length];
                byte[] fileNameLen = BitConverter.GetBytes(fileNameByte.Length);

                fileNameLen.CopyTo(clientData, 0);
                fileNameByte.CopyTo(clientData, 4);
                fileData.CopyTo(clientData, 4 + fileNameByte.Length);


                clientSock.Send(clientData);
               //MessageBox.Show("File:{0} has been sent." + fileName);
            }
            //sock.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
            //sock.Close();


           // Console.ReadLine();
            //sendme();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("File Receiving fail." + ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

client side code:

```
public class StateObject
    {
        // Client socket.
        public Socket workSocket = null;

        public const int BufferSize = 1024;
        // Receive buffer.
        public byte[] buffer = new byte[BufferSize];
    }

    public static ManualResetEvent allDone = new ManualResetEvent(false);

    public void StartListening()
    {
        byte[] bytes = new Byte[1024];
        IPAddress address = IPAddress.Parse(ServerIP);
        IPEndPoint ipEnd = new IPEndPoint(address, 9050);
        Socket listener = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        try
        {
            listener.Bind(ipEnd);
            listener.Listen(100);

            while (true)
            {
                allDone.Reset();
                // string ip = listener.RemoteEndPoint.ToString();
                listener.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(AcceptCallback), listener);
                allDone.WaitOne();

            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }


    }


    public void AcceptCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {

        allDone.Set();


        Socket listener = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;
        Socket handler = listener.EndAccept(ar);


        StateObject state = new StateObject();
        state.workSocket = handler;
        handler.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0,
        new AsyncCallback(ReadCallback), state);
        flag = 0;
    }

    public void ReadCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {

        try
        {

            int fileNameLen = 1;
            String content = String.Empty;
            StateObject state = (StateObject)ar.AsyncState;
            Socket handler = state.workSocket;
            //string[] str = new string[2];
            //str = handler.RemoteEndPoint.ToString().Split(':');
            string path = mypath + "@Login.XML";
            if (!Directory.Exists(path))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
            }

            int bytesRead = handler.EndReceive(ar);

            if (bytesRead > 0)
            {

                if (flag == 0)
                {
                    fileNameLen = BitConverter.ToInt32(state.buffer, 0);
                    string fileName = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(state.buffer, 4, fileNameLen);
                    receivedPath = mypath + "@Login.XML";
                    flag++;
                }
                if (flag >= 1)
                {
                    BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(File.Open(receivedPath, FileMode.Append));
                    if (flag == 1)
                    {
                        writer.Write(state.buffer, 4 + fileNameLen, bytesRead - (4 + fileNameLen));
                        flag++;
                    }
                    else
                        writer.Write(state.buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                    writer.Close();
                    handler.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0,
                    new AsyncCallback(ReadCallback), state);
                }

            }
            else
            {

                Invoke(new MyDelegate(LabelWriter));
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);

        }
    }
    public void LabelWriter()
    {
       MessageBox.Show("Data has been received");
       Programs p = new Programs();
       p.GetFile(serverIP);
    }
```

this code is used to get file from server.

```
private void GetLoginTemp()
    {
        Socket clientSock = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        try
        {
            char[] delimiter = splitter.ToCharArray();
            byte[] fileName = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("empty"); //file name
            byte[] fileData;
            fileData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("empty");
            //byte[] fileData = reads.ReadToEnd().to; //file
            byte[] fileNameLen = BitConverter.GetBytes(fileName.Length); //lenght of file name
            clientData = new byte[4 + fileName.Length + fileData.Length];

            fileNameLen.CopyTo(clientData, 0);
            fileName.CopyTo(clientData, 4);
            fileData.CopyTo(clientData, 4 + fileName.Length);
            System.Net.IPAddress ipAdd = System.Net.IPAddress.Parse(serverIP);

            IPEndPoint ipEnd = new IPEndPoint(ipAdd, 9050);
            clientSock.Connect(ipEnd); //target machine's ip address and the port number
            clientSock.Send(clientData);

            byte[] clientData1 = new byte[1024 * 5000];
            string receivedPath = mypath + @"\XML" + @"\Login.xml";

            int receivedBytesLen = clientSock.Receive(clientData1);

            int fileNameLen1 = BitConverter.ToInt32(clientData1, 0);
            string fileName1 = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(clientData1, 4, fileNameLen1);

            BinaryWriter bWrite = new BinaryWriter(File.Open(receivedPath + fileName, FileMode.Append)); ;
            bWrite.Write(clientData, 4 + fileNameLen1, receivedBytesLen - 4 - fileNameLen1);
            //clientSock.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Send);

            clientSock.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            clientSock.Close();
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You seem to think that you need a second TCP connection in the direction where the file is going. This is not necessary since TCP connection is a **full-duplex stream**. Also it's never a good design to connect from server back to client, which might be behind a NAT-ing gateway/firewall. This is the problem with FTP (see [active vs passive ftp](http://slacksite.com/other/ftp.html)).

Use the same connection the client has already established. You need some sort of protocol on top of base TCP to let the other side know when to expect data and how much to expect. This has been discussed here many times, see for example [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1531207/).

Answer (score 0):

Just from the error you are getting (I have gotten the same error many many times) Check that the underlying stream you are using for your communication is not closed, or that you're not attempting to re-use a closed stream.

Do you have a specific line where the error is occurring?

Comment: Brandon i face that error

"No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 192.168.1.5:9050"

this error i face in senddata function.

Comment: Do you have a line number or any other information? 

I looked through the code and I think you may be attempting to perform the server-side code on both client and server. You need to have one side as a listener and one that actively goes out and seeks the listener when it needs the data. Because TCP is connection-oriented, it is after the initial connection that all transmission should take place using the stream established on the connection.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check the system firewalls to ensure the connection is allowed. The use of ping and telnet are great for debugging.

Answer (score 0):

If it's not the Firewall, I think it's as simple as to put the server to listen (to start the server)

I suggest this piece of code would solve your problem:

```
var prg = StateObject();
prg.StartListening;
```

After you'll manage this, please tell me if file over 8KB is sent full