# Reliable check if tcp packet has been delivered

Tags: c, sockets, tcp, packet

I'm trying to implement a simple instant messenger server and came up with the following problem:

How can I reliable check if the message has been arrived at the other endpoint? (I know there are acknowledge packets but I have no idea to implement it the right way).

Example code:

Client:

```c
/* connect and stuff... */
connect(serverFD, ...)
write(serverFD, "hello there!, 13);
/* Give the server a little time */
sleep(1);
/* Close the socket, simulate connection lost scenario */
shutdown(serverFD, SHUT_RDWR);
```

Server:

```c
clientFD = accept(masterSocket, NULL, NULL);
/* Read a package */
{
    char buf[20];
    ssize_t buflen = read(clientFD, buf, sizeof(buf));
    fprintf(stderr, "%zd bytes read: %s\n", buf);
    /* Wait 2 seconds */
    sleep(2);
    /* Send a message to the closed endpoint */
    // NO SIGPIPE signal!
    write(clientFD, "hello!", 7);
}
```

The problem is how can the server know if the message has been delivered or not? `write` returns no error at all.

**EDIT** I know there is a similar question about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1531207/finding-out-if-a-message-over-tcp-was-delivered) but there is no explanation about the acknowledge packet.

Comment: The fact that you don't understand the linked answers does not justify another question. This question must be significantly different from the other question. Closing. Maybe you should ask a new question about how to implement an ack packet.

Comment: You aren't just interested in a TCP packet. Note that `"hello!"` could (in theory) be split up into multiple TCP packets. I don't know of a way to check that all buffered socket data has been sent and ACKed, but [this may be of interest to you](http://blog.netherlabs.nl/articles/2009/01/18/the-ultimate-so_linger-page-or-why-is-my-tcp-not-reliable).

Comment: @urs OK I made a new question asking for acknowledge packets.