# Does Unix socket programming ensure no transmission loss or will I have to incorporate it at application level?

Tags: c, unix, tcp

Theoretically TCP/IP has guaranteed delivery. But in practice, if the server goes down or there's a failure in the connection link, then how can I ensure that all packets which need to be sent are sent? 
Also how does the sender come to know which packets are successfully sent. 
I am trying to implement tcp protocol in C.
 In previous blog i read that the send() function will return -1 only if problem has occured in the sender and may not return -1 if there is a transmission failure. Also i read if i set SO_SNDBUFR to packet size it the sender will be blocked till ack is received. Is this correct?

Comment: If the server you are communicating with goes down then you probably have other problems you need to think about. And no you won't loose any message you try to send, as TCP will make sure you get an error returned when attempting to send so you still have the data and can retry once the communication have been reestablished.

Comment: Be careful with terminology - a "Unix socket" is a specific kind of socket that is not a TCP/IP one!

Comment: Just design/code whatever you need. Look at the designs of existing protocols layered over TCP to see how it's normally done. (In other words, yes, do it at application level.)

Answer (score 0):

If you use `send` to send data through TCP socket and want to confirm that the data is delivered successfully, then the short answer is yes, you need to do it at application level.

A simple example is to let the other side send acknowledgement like a single byte. So you `recv` a single byte after `send`. That indicates it's delivered successfully.

This kind of logic is common, e.g. client application may sync some data remotely and need to tell the user everything is done, as soon as possible.

You can find some similar questions on SO for some reading, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1531207/finding-out-if-a-message-over-tcp-was-delivered).

Answer (score 0):

There is no kind of socket which ensures ***no*** transmission loss. There are levels of assurance only.

For example, in TCP, a supposed guaranteed delivery system, if you have a network outage it may be several minutes before the receiving party is notified by the system that this has occurred. Even then, this will only occur if some event happens which brings this to the attention of the system, such as: The recipient tries to send something to the server, or heartbeats have been enabled (they are off by default) and the heartbeat timeout has passed.

**Therefore every system requires a mechanism to recover from transmission errors and any associated data loss.**

Even if the sent packets are sent, and acknowledged as received by the receiving machine, the receiving application may have crashed before processing them.

If every packet is important at the application level, you must provide an application level protocol to make sure they are received.

In your case it sounds like you may want some kind of message queueing system.

The same logic applies at [Layer 8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Layer_8) of the OSI stack: If you want to be sure that a **person** has seen your message, you must get an acknowledgement *from the person*. A read receipt is sent by the mail program and does not mean a person has read it, let alone understood it.

Comment: Where can i find the basics for implementing message queuing system in C ?

Comment: There are numerous libraries for this, but without knowing what it is you are making I can't recommend any or even say for sure that it is the appropriate course.