# How to verify ACK packet with write function in TCP client?

Tags: c, sockets, tcp, tcpclient

I'm trying to write a TCP client with [write function](https://linux.die.net/man/3/write) following this: [guide](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/tcp-server-client-implementation-in-c/).

I shut down my network and try to send a PING package with 2 bytes of data.

Since it's a TCP client, I expect some kind of error returned because there is no network at all and the server won't be able to receive the message, hence no ACK packet will be returned. However, **write function** returns 2 bytes were written, seem like it doesn't verify **ACK packet** from server side at all.

How could I check for **ACK** to make sure whether my message is sent successfully and server receive it?

Comment: Write only returns if the data were successfully submitted to the local OS kernel. It says nothing about data received at the other end. If you want to have something like this you need to implement it at your application level, i.e. let the peer explicitly reply with an application level acknowledgement or so.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding out if a message over tcp was delivered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1531207/finding-out-if-a-message-over-tcp-was-delivered)

Answer (score 1):

If you run both client and server on the same machine they'll communicate through the loopback interface, so unplugging or deactivating the outbound network interface will not change anything. Your server and client communicate happily with each other. If there truly isn't any connection between server and client the `connect()` should've failed with errno set to `ENETUNREACH` or `ECONNREFUSED` if the server refuses the connection. So what you probably want is to run the client on your machine and the server either another computer or in a VM with a bridged network. Note that `write()` successfully returning only means that the bytes are buffered to be send. It may even return fewer bytes than your message contains, indicating the buffer is currently full and you need to try sending the remaining bytes later.

The best way to analyze protocol implementations is using a tool like wireshark to see what packages are actually sent over the wire (or through the loopback interface).

Comment: I'm trying to send message to a remote server, not in the same local network. I called the function `connect()` when network is still up so it doesn't fire any complaint, I only cut down the network after `connect()` and before `write()`. 

Btw, as @Steffen commented above, I misunderstand the use of `write()` function, maybe I need some kind of PING response on app layer to verify the ACK.

Comment: @ToanTran right. You could make the server write a message (conceptually on the application layer) that indicates he's done with whatever data you've send it. Just for accuracy in case somebody else reads this, a PING usually means something different than what you're referring to. PINGs are packets delivered through ICMP which doesn't involve TCP at all.