# TCP Java Socket custom timeouts not working only on docker

Tags: java, docker, sockets, tcp, docker-compose

This code works **perfectly on my machine** default O.S but **not in Docker**, and I didn't found any documentation about it.

```
    clientSocket = new Socket();

    SocketAddress sockaddr = new InetSocketAddress(propertyFile.getProperty("tcp.pod.ip"),
            Integer.parseInt(propertyFile.getProperty("tcp.pod.port")));

    clientSocket.connect(sockaddr, 150);

    clientSocket.setTcpNoDelay(true);
```

The part that does not work in docker is the clientSocket **connect timeout**(second parameter), it takes the default timeout instead the one I am passing to him. Everything else works perfectly.

Comment: Please add your Dockerfile's content. Did you use the EXPOSE instruction?

Comment: This socket runs on your host, and you want to connect to it from your container?

Comment: Dockerfile and docker-compose-yml added

Comment: Define 'does not work'.

Comment: It takes the default timeout instead the timeout I pass in the function

Comment: Does it? Default timeout such as what?

Comment: I left it running for more than 30 seconds and still did not recognize the timeout(and I disconnect the prototype). Without docker is exactly the time I pass in the function 150 ms or whatever.

Comment: I found this on other post "The number of retries and the interval between them is determined by the OS implementation of TCP/IP, and Java doesn't provide a way either find out what these values are, or change them."

Comment: You didn't answer my question. What default timeout did you experience? And how is the number of retries relevant?

Comment: I know that running that without docker it works and with docker do not, and the behavior is the same as if I put a very long value in the second parameter of the socker.connect function. I did not measure the exact time, I quit it after 30 seconds during various test. I will try to provide this afternoon or tomorrow the exact time by lefting it all the time necessary running, and two shorts videos

Comment: For example, if a put 9000 ms. If I disconnect the board I see the disconnection after 9 seconds if I put 150 ms I see the disconnection almost inmediately but in docker I never see it. I quit the test after 30 seconds, I imagine the problem is with the socket

Comment: Everything else work as well in docker as without it. I thought it could be because of different implemetations or because as this docker image is not an entire linux because of conflicts

Comment: 'Never see it again' contradicts 'takes the default timeout', which is about a minute.

Comment: Yes you are right @user207421 . What I want to know is why it takes the default time, or what is going on and how can I solve it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have been testing for months but the telemetry was just from our O.S through two access points to the prototypes, so if an ack is not received because the protopype died I will see it(We were using this to see if there were communication)

With docker there is a proxy between the O.S and the docker engine so you will see always there is connection because the acks arrives always from the container to the O.S socket.

The solution to implement a keep alive in the application layer(you can not do this in the protocol layer).

This post explain it better: [Finding out if a message over tcp was delivered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1531207/finding-out-if-a-message-over-tcp-was-delivered)